# how to invoke Spring Portlet

Tags: spring, portlet, portal

I have been reading and following the spring doc on how to create Spring Portlet and I have most of the configurations and a basic controller done. But I don't know how to invoke it. In Spring MVC, we can config a url so that we can invoke that controller. but how is it done in Spring Portlet? It doesn't mention in the documentation, I think.

I also read the following article and it doesn't say how to config the portlet either.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0802_patil-pt1/0802_patil-pt1.html

In Oracle WebCenter, to config a portlet, we need a url. What would be the url for the Spring Portlet then.

Answer (score 0):

While  configuring Portlet in Jboss portal server only Portlet class name is enough.

Check this to do in Oracle WebCenter [Creating Java Portlets](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B32110_01/webcenter.1013/b31074/jpsdg_java_intro.htm#CEGGEFDD)

Comment: is there a way that i can test it via a url to see the result?

Comment: I also tried this example and it seems to provide a url, but it doesn't work either @ http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13158_01/alui/jsr168consumer/docs103/devguide/

Comment: doesn't work. i also tried http://localhost:8084/PortletDemo/portlet/HelloWorldPortlet/mode/view according to the example.

Comment: just 404. HTTP Status 404 - /PortletDemo/portlet/HelloWorldPortlet/mode/view